# How to add metadata about a collection in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a script (node.js) which periodically ping (every 10 sec) a mongoose collection to see if there are new documments added. I want the query to be as fast as possible. Is it possible to write metadata about a collection?

For example: I would like to push the title of each new document in a (global) array for each new document inserted so the script will just have to read this array and erase it after: no need to go through all the documents and check if date > (now() - 10 sec).

Comment: Hm, what's wrong with having `createdAt` property for each document and then search for `createdAt > the date of the last one you've queried`?

Comment: mongoose have a mechanism of versioning a document, see if it can help you:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey

Comment: I'm worrying that if there is a lot a documents in the collection and I have to query it every 10 sec it might become very slow

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to now if the collection has changed you can run a `count` query:

```
Query#count([criteria], [callback])

Specifying this query as a count query.

Parameters:

[criteria] <Object> mongodb selector
[callback] <Function>
Returns:

<Query> this
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-count
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/

Comment: It seems to be a good solution since the collection should not change frequently